# Can not upload ipa to TestFlight in Xcode 13 with error: The request timed out

Tags: swift, testflight, xcode13

I've updated Xcode to version 13.1 recently. After that, I can't use Xcode to upload ipa to TestFlight. I've received the error "The request timed out".
[image]

Because of this problem, my CI/CD doesn't work anymore because it can't distribute ipa using Xcode. (my runner using Xcode 13.x )
[image]

I've tried 4-5 different apps but I still faced the same error.
If I export file ipa, then use Transporter app to distribute ipa => It pushes ipa to TestFlight successfully.
I don't face this problem on Xcode 12.

Has anyone faced or known how to solve this problem? Thank in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should take a look here:
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/699749

In short - it seems that the altool bundled with xCode 13.2.1 is buggy and the workaround is just to use an altool from a different xCode version.

https://github.com/revolut-mobile/altool-binary

Answer (score -1):

Just had the same issue...

All I did was try over and over. The 4th time worked for me. I waited about 10min after each try.

**Xcode version:** Version 13.2.1 (13C100)

Definitely worth trying [Boyan Kirov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71162476/9669133).